# XSLT error when getting variable

Tags: variables, xslt, webharvest

I am trying to assign variables into xsl file and use them later in this file.

Here is how i assign them:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="matches(normalize-space(tokenize((//span[@class='timark' and matches(.,'Наименование и адрес')]/following-sibling::div[1]/p[@class='addr'])[1],',')[1]), 'BG[0-9]')">


        <xsl:variable name="authtitle" select="normalize-space(tokenize((//span[@class='timark' and matches(.,'Наименование и адрес')]/following-sibling::div[1]/p[@class='addr'])[1],',')[2])" />

        <xsl:variable name="authstreet" select="normalize-space(tokenize((//span[@class='timark' and matches(.,'Наименование и адрес')]/following-sibling::div[1]/p[@class='addr'])[1],',')[3])" />

    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>


        <xsl:variable name="authtitle" select="normalize-space(tokenize((//span[@class='timark' and matches(.,'Наименование и адрес')]/following-sibling::div[1]/p[@class='addr'])[1],',')[1])" />

        <xsl:variable name="authstreet" select="normalize-space(tokenize((//span[@class='timark' and matches(.,'Наименование и адрес')]/following-sibling::div[1]/p[@class='addr'])[1],',')[2])" />

    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

And when i try to use them

```
<name>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$authtitle" />
                    </name>
```

I get Error! Why?

If i remove only the

```
<xsl:value-of select="$authtitle" />
```

line , it is OK. So it seems i am not accessing the variable correctly.

Comment: Can you provide the error you get?

Comment: Please show us the exact error message.

Comment: Your mistake is the same one as in the duplicate question. In other words, the solution there applies to this problem as well.